# Why I cannot set up permissions to my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I cannot open my hard drive because it shows me:

> “Disc is not available - Access denied”

It is visible via disk management and it says:

> “Healthy, Active”

But when I want to get info about disc occupancy it shows me just `0`.

What can I do?

Comment: I have big doubts about your disk.

Comment: Why do you think it?

Comment: Your post is unclear and doesn't allow a sure answer, but I hope you have backups.

Comment: Which information do you need? I can update it.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution working just on your PC. If use another PC need to do the same process below again.

If I check permissions for disc it shows me `You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object.`

The steps to fix it (Win10) are here:

1. Click by right mouse button on disc and choose `properties`
2. `Security`
3. `Advanced`
4. See Unable to display current owner - click on `Change` button
5. Enter your user name and click on `Check Names` and `OK`
6. Then you can see users in table below and click to `Apply`
7. Again open `Properties` and click `Security`
8. Click on `Edit` and remove current users
9. Add new user `Add` as step 5
10. If shows error just click `Continue`

And everything is working fine.

Comment: Link-only answers are low quality; they will be useless if the linked resource disappears. For the answer to be useful for future users with similar problems, the procedure should be described *here*. Now the right thing to do is to [edit] the answer and make it standalone.